How to check if Relay Chain has Async Backing enabled?
According to the Async backing guide, the relay chain needs to have async backing enabled, so I was wondering what is the easiest way to check if some active relay chain (Rococo or Zombienet relay) has it enable, without finding the relay-chain configuration.

To check if the relay chain has async backing enabled, users can go to Polkadot-js link, access the Developer -> Runtime calls page, and select parachainHost -> asyncBackingParams() call and execute it. If it returns same as on the picture below, it is enabled.


It doesn't need to return the exact same values, but they should not be zero.
